# Is this the process through which you would formally define addition of a set of numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can the addition operation be formally defined without direct reference to the axioms assuming the set operations are well defined from the axioms and the existence and uniqueness of such sets are guaranteed by the axioms?

for example, would this definition suffice assuming the natural numbers, the successor operation (denoted S(x)), and functions were all well-defined concepts?

$+_n(x)=\{(x,y):(\forall x,y,n,m)((x,y,n,m\in \mathbb{N}) \land(x=m\iff y=y_1) \implies(x=\emptyset \implies y=n)\lor(x=S(m)\implies y=S(y_1)))\}$

This may be a bit wordy or clunky and possibly awkward to work with, but am I on the right track? If this is a possible definition of a function defining addition, then I can define an operation for the function.

Comment: addition is an operation...

Comment: I know, but it can, in this case, be defined as a function, from which we can define the operation in a very similar way. This definition provides pairs,(x,y), for which the sum of a natural number n and x are equal to y. I can then define the output of the operation as the set of y values alone.

Comment: Addition is a bynary *operation* i.e. to every pair of numbers as input, it outputs a number. Thus, as a function (i.e. a relation) it is a *ternary* relation : $((n,m),k) \text { iff } k=+_n(m)$

Comment: so would it be right to put it as $+(n,m)=\{((n,m),y):(\forall x,y,n,m)((x,y,n,m\in \mathbb{N}) \land(m=x\iff y=y_1) \implies(m=\emptyset \implies y=n)\lor(m=S(x)\implies y=S(y_1)))\}$

Comment: all operations are necessarily functions...

Answer (score 1):

See Herbert Enderton, [Elements of set theory (Academic Press, 1977)](https://books.google.it/books?id=JlR-Ehk35XkC&pg=PA79), page 79.

In set-theoretic terms, we have to use the [Recursion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem).

Having defined $0= \emptyset$ and $s(n)=n \cup \{ n \}$ and denoting with $\omega$ the set of *natural* numbers, the definition of addition runs as follows :

*(i)* for each $n \in \omega$, define the function $A_n : \omega \to \omega$ as :

> $A_n(0)=n$
>
> $A_n(s(m))=s(A_n(m))$.

The Recursion theorem ensures that such a function exists and is unique.

Then, *(ii)* define a function $+$ from $\omega \times \omega \to \omega$ as :

> $+(n,m)=A_n(m)$,

i.e. $+ = \{ ((n,m),k) \mid n,m \in \omega \text { and } k=A_n(m) \}.$

Comment: Thanks, but out of curiosity, why is this theorem necessary? What in particular was wrong with my definition (I'm sure that list is probably long)?